# Unable to add external jar into application jar file

Tags: java, maven

I use external jar `jimObjModelImporterJFX.jar`, because it's not hosted on Maven repository and I'm adding it with maven dependency like below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jimObjModelImporterJFX</groupId>
        <artifactId>jimObjModelImporterJFX</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${path}</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I could not add it in IntelliJ by `Project Structure` -> `Modules` -> `Dependencies` -> `+` because later on I'd have errors during maven task.

Then I have plugin to add dependencies (but it's not adding and I don't know why, but on other topics people say that it should)

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>myMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After that I run maven task `clean compile assembly:single` and when it's done I have a `jar` in `target` folder.

When I run it from cmd I have an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.ImportException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

It's because my application jar file doesn't contains this library inside. Structure is like:
archive
|-groupid.artifactid (.class files here)
|-layouts (with .fxml file because it's javaFX app)
|-META-INF (with MANIFEST.MF)

How to put this `jimObjModelImporterJFX.jar` into my app?

Answer (score 2):

`system` dependencies will never end up in the resulting jar by definition. They are supposed to be explicitly provided.

You can add the jar to your local .m2 repository using the maven command line util `mvn` like this

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-jar-file> \
                         -DgroupId=<yourGroupId> \
                         -DartifactId=<yourArtifactId> \
                         -Dversion=<yourVersion> \
                         -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then use the "normal" dependency notation

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>yourGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>yourArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>yourVersion</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I cannot build it with command ./mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jimObjModelImporterJFX.jar -DgroupId=com.interactivemesh -DartifactId=jfx -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackagin=jar because I have an error The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:  [0]  'packaging' is missing.

Comment: I found out that -Dpackaging should be before -Dversion, then it works

Comment: everything works fine now with my building task etc. Thanks!

Comment: The order of command line options is not relevant. But it seems like you misspelled "packagin**g**" as "packagin" in your first comment